# Is there an acceptable way to split classes into smaller, composeable mixins (which know about the parent) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mixins, sorbet

I find that some classes in Ruby, especially the `User` class in Ruby on Rails, have a tendency to become absolutely enormous. That in itself is just about manageagable but the tests files for such large classes also become massive too.

To try and compartmentalise this complexity I would like to compose the user Class from several sub-classes.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include User::AuthMixin
  include User::EmailsMixin
  include User::SettingsMixin
end
```

Technically this works however it means that the Mixins end up referencing a bunch of properties on the User object that they don't actually know anything about. Take this EmailsMixin which compartmentalises all of the logic around multiple-emails per user:

```
module User::EmailsMixin

  def email
    primary_email.try :value
  end

  def update_email value
    email = emails.build value: value
    self.primary_email = email
  end
  ...
end
```

### This works but it doesn't smell real good...

While this all works it feels like bad smelling code. Why should the `User::EmailsMixin` be referencing a primary_email that it doesn't have any knowledge of? And this will be the nature of the mixins - they are all referencing properties on the parent object (which is the User in this case).

Not only this but now I'm using Sorbet Typechecking it doesn't pass typechecking. Sorbet points out precisely this error and states that `Method primary_email does not exist on User::EmailsMixin`. Which of course is true.

So I have three questions:

1. Is this a reasonable paradigm for compartmentalising code? Please note that this is not code that can be moved into service objects, it relates directly to attributes on the user object (as per above)
2. If it is a reasonable paradigm is there a way that reference the parent object in each of the mixins? Is there a way to say "this module is in fact part of the User object and will be included/merged later"
3. If this isn't a reasonable way of breaking down vast classes into smaller ones then how else should I consider doing so (to re-iterate, service objects won't cut it here as the code *needs* to access the parent properties)

Comment: I think it isn't exactly a question for Stack Overflow, maybe Code Review. However, IMO, I think you can use some smart Value Objects here. Also, you can define the method in the module and raise NotImplementedError, that way we know that whatever includes the module will have to implement this method.

Comment: In some cases breaking down a large class into a bunch of modules actually just decreases the quality of the code. You may have reduced the number of lines in the file but you're really just spreading it out into modules where its harder for maintainers to find. Even when you decompose a god object into modules its still a god object, and models in Rails have a tendency to become god objects since they have so many responsibilities. Instead you want to consider where you can split this into separate objects (models, services, decorators etc).

Comment: Richard Scheeman has [a really good writeup on the topic](https://rollout.io/blog/good-module-bad-module/). I know you think you can't split this code into seperate objects but if you reason about what this code does instead of how its implemented you might come to see that this is not the case.

Comment: @Eyeslandic please don't use the existence of the Code Review site as a reason to close a question. Evaluate the request and use a reason like *needs more focus* (as I have done now), *primarily opinion-based*, etc. Then you can mention to the OP that it can be posted on Code Review if it is [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please see [_Does being on-topic at another Stack Exchange site automatically make a question off-topic for Stack Overflow?_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353)

Comment: @Eyeslandic my point is not that this isn't a code review request but rather that you should use a legitimate reason to close it here... this should be explained by the answers to [that meta post I included a link to](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400/1575353).

Comment: I have asked the  Sorbet team about the type checking part specifically: https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/issues/3868

Answer (score 1):

There's no way to give a concrete answer without looking at all of your code and refactoring accordingly to *your use case*.

In my view, mixins (or Rails concerns) should be used very sparingly. They do nothing to reduce the surface area of the code (public interface is still the same "logical size"), and they only serve to hide things away and make things harder to find. This is the same reason deep inheritance can become unwieldy -- the "logical size" of a class is itself plus all of its superclasses. Moving code to another file does nothing to change that.

Without knowing exactly what you code is doing, I'm going to make a blind suggestion that often applies: separate persistence from domain logic. For example, I think it's fine to have `#email` and `#update_email` remain in `User`, because they deal with *persistence*, and having them close to the Model is fine b/c interfacing /w the DB is the model's responsibility.

However, if you were looking for a place for a `#validate_email` method, neither `User` nor `Email` models would be a good place to put it.

There is always more than one way to divide up your application, and as you've noticed, dividing up purely by responsibility (Emails, Auth, Settings), means you're *not* dividing by *data access*/persistence, i.e. "everything needs access to `User` properties".

If you divide by data, you'd find that these modules *don't* need access to (all) the properties of `User`. `Auth` probably only needs `login` and `hashed_pass`. `Settings` probably only needs a single hash.

With the logic moved out of `User`, you'll need to pass data out for processing retrieve the results when done -- this is the data interface between components you'll want to maintain. If it starts getting complex, perhaps the data interface itself should be a class/datatype. If you start needing to pass too many parameters, think about if whether the boundaries between components are in the right place.

A warning -- many rails libraries don't make this distinction, often suggesting you `include`/`extend` your models to access their functionality, so you'll have to find a way to work with that if you want to use them.